# dynamically increase the relative layout size in android

Tags: android

i have a relative layout on which i am displaying a page and some content. when i zoom my page...the layout size is not increasing. i want my layout to increase its size dynamically. how do i set it??
i tried doing it in java code.

```
contentLayout.getLayoutParams().height = x (some value which is equal to the page size)
contentLayout.requestLayout()
```

but this is nt working. i have also set the layout params `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `wrap-content` in the xml file.

Kindly, help me out. thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it this way. I also added setting of the margins:

```
RelativeLayout targetItem = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adaptLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mWidth, mHeight);
adaptLayout.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight, marginBottom);   
targetItem.setLayoutParams(adaptLayout);
```

For mWidth and mHeight you also may set `dip` values to make it adapt to the different screen sizes. Easy way to do that is to define Dimension in your `strings.xml` and work with them, not with absolute values.

So, if you define `relative_width` as 120dip, and `relative_height` as 100 dip then in code you have

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adaptLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.relative_width), getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.relative_height));
```

Comment: thank u.. its working..i am displaying my page on surface view.. its working but my page is invisible.

Comment: You mean that my solution caused that issue?

Comment: no.. . but its the issue with surface view.. i am displaying my page on surface view. once i altered this layout dimensions... my page is lost.. do not know the reason.

Comment: But SurfaceView is not mentioned in your answer. I answered what you asked, and that is checked code that works correctly for me.