# can i increase the relative layout size when in zoom mode in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamically increase the relative layout size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038130/dynamically-increase-the-relative-layout-size-in-android)

can i increase the relative layout size when in zoom mode in android

Answer (score -1):

well you dont need to worry about that... being a relative layout, it fits automatically

Comment: i am displaying a page in relative layout. my page is getting zoomed but not my relative layout. its staying fixed beyond the emulator size.